# Can server-side javascript detect new users added to a list/data extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I want to add a user to a list or possibly update a user(through the API probably), and from there fire off an email.  Now I know I can do an hourly script to run a SSJS to fire the emails, but I can't figure out how I would go about actually detect the new or updated user.

Comment: You can detect the insert or update event inside a Trigger.

Comment: @SarojBera thanks, but could you be a little more specific?  The client has an API call that adds a user to list and that's all they want to do in the transaction.  They don't want to handle the logic for handling the triggered send on their side, which is normally where the email send would come from.  So I need to leverage SFMC to detect that a user has been added/updated to a list and trigger an email send.  Are you still saying there is some kind of "Trigger" inside ET that I'm not seeing in the tool?  Thanks

Comment: Erik, @SarojBera's confused about which software and technology he's referring to. You're question's about Marketing Cloud and he has a Sales Cloud Solution for you that confuses things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, are you using Lists or Data Extensions?

SSJS could do a retrieve on your Subscribers or Data Extension records if they have a created or updated field and do something, I suppose. But it's not the way you would build this.

If you're using Lists, you could maybe consider letting the [Welcome Email associated with the list](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/resources/solution_guides/welcome_email/assign_a_welcome_email_to_a_list/) do the to work of sending an email. For this to work you would need to use [WebCollect](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/web_collect/) specifically and not the API. But that approach would trigger an email and create a subscriber immediately from a really simple HTTP request.

A Triggered Send from SOAP or REST using a specific list in the Triggered Send Definition would upsert the customer to the list specified, also, and send the email.

If you're using data extensions, you could make two API calls to firstly Add the Customer record to the Data Extension and the second you could use to do the triggered send. Both calls are CreateRequests, so you could place these two actions in a single SOAP call.

Another approach could be to simply do a triggered send through the API using a Triggered Send Data Extension. You could then use the data in this data extension to update your user data in a Data Extension though a Query Activity after the fact as part of an automation.

Comment: Yeah so the answer seems to be there is no way to do this the way to client wants, but I'm going to mark yours as the correct answer because that is the only way to do this.  I was going to do an hourly SSJS script that would take anyone from one list and trigger the welcome using the API in my SFMC instance and then move them to a new list.  However, I got the client to compromise and just do it the right way by calling the triggered send api from the original script.